# What IP address should mongoose connect to in production mode?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'am hosting a webapp from my home server using node.js and Express. I would like to add mongoose to my app, however I am not sure what IP address should be put in my app file in order to enable mongodb for production mode.

Normally, while in development mode something like this should be added:

```
db = connect("127.0.0.1:27017/myDatabase")
```

Now that I'm in production mode I'm not exactly sure what is the IP address that should be referenced in order to use the exact same machine that is hosting the app as a database. Any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Application Services and DB on the same machine, you can use localhost or 127.0.0.1.

If you use use AWS Instance for DB, then you can see IP attached with DB. use that IP and dont forgot to open port 27017 for your Instance to enable traffic on that port.
* Note: If you haven't attached elastic IP to instance. then restarting DB instance will have new IP. So it is good to attache Elastic IP.

If you are using AWS Subnet, then using Local IP, you can use Local IP address of Instance.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address (or perhaps [FQDN](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aiuv)) you use for your connection depends on what machine you used when you started the `mongod` command. Whatever IP address that machine has is the IP address you want to use. Note that if you specified a port number for your `mongod` command you will need to change that in your connection as well.

Its also worth noting that you should not assume that your app and database will be running on the same machine. In fact, if you're running in production they generally wont be. For that reason you probably want to pass in the address to your database machine via a config file.